# IBM MQ issue with cluster queue

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

Not able to put a message to a cluster queue on a remote queue manager. I am using MQGetMessageOptions and MQPutMessageOptions. I am using 7.5 MQ server and client (7.5.0.1)

It throws reason code - 2085- message -CompCode: 2, Reason: 2085

The queue and queue manager are connected using MQ clusters.

```
 mqQueue = mqQueueMgr.AccessQueue("queue name", MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE);
```

I tried to put a test message using amqsput.exe it works fine there.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

This call:

```
mqQueue = mqQueueMgr.AccessQueue("queue name", MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE);
```

opens the cluster queue for getting messages. To get messages, application must be connected to the local queue manager. A local queue manager means the queue manager to which your application is connected. The queue manager can be on the same machine as your application or on a different machine. Messages can't be got from a remote queue manager. Messages can be put a cluster queue when application is connected to a different queue manager in the cluster than the queue manager that hosts the cluster queue.

`AMQSPUT` works because it is opening the queue for Put and not for Get.

So to solve your problem the option must be changed as:

```
mqQueue = mqQueueMgr.AccessQueue("queue name", MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT);
```

Comment: Thanks , can i add MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT at the end like shown below instead of removing other entries(so that this will work for both local and cluster queues)?

mqQueue = mqQueueMgr.AccessQueue("queue name", MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT);

Comment: No. It will still fail if you add MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT. You have to remove INPUT_SHARED and BROWSE options. To get messages from a cluster queue application must be connected to the queue manager where the cluster queue is hosted.

Comment: This is my send method to put a message

   mqQueue = mqQueueMgr.AccessQueue("queue name", MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE);

Do i need to change anything above?

Comment: You have to remove INPUT_SHARED and INQUIRE options for putting messages. Just have MQOO_OUTPUT and MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING. This will work for both local and cluster queues.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  MQQueue queue = queueManageArg.AccessQueue(queueNameArg,
                MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
```

to put message to MQ