# How to get message from a queue hosted in another queue manager in IBM MQ cluster

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

According to this: [IBM MQ issue with cluster queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076247/ibm-mq-issue-with-cluster-queue) we cant get message from a queue hosted on another queue manager with this code:

```
mqQueue = mqQueueMgr.AccessQueue("queue name", MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED);
```

Is there any way to get message without connecting to that queue manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the problem with your code. It is by MQ design that only applications directly connected to queue manager can get messages.

It would be useful if you can explain your scenario a little more to see if there are any alternatives.

Comment: I have 2 matrices and want to multiply them with nodes in a cluster. One node get the matrices and put the rows and columns in a queue. I want other queues get that messages and calculates the answer and put answers in another queue. because the number of nodes is relative i don't want the first node put message to other queues.